# How can i apply the total width of the container dynamically counting the total width of the children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typo3

I have dynamic number of containers which again contains dynamic of children elements. I need to count the sum of the children elements and apply the total width to its parent.

Here is the page : http://test.mosaiq-media.de/ekz/index.php?id=14

Here i need to calculate the total width of ".m-stage--container" from its child elements ".span3, .span6, .span3".

Now i have done a shortcut formula of taking the ".row" width using float:left. But this wont work on small resolution...because ".row" can take maximun width of the screen.

```
$(".content-wrapper .m-stage .row").css('float','left');
$(".content-wrapper .m-stage").each(function(n){
    $(this).find(".m-stage--container").width($(this).find(".m-stage--container > .row").width() - 10);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WOuld you mind using JQuery to do it?

Comment: Jquery is tagged, so I guess its okay to use it ;]. @Rajiv007, could you provide your code in the question. Then it will keep its value, even when your website is down.

Comment: already using jquery...see updates for current code.

Comment: `.span3` and `.span6` have the widths in css and you know them (you can get them). What do you want at all, why setting `float: left` to row?

Comment: @skobaljic ...yes ".span3" and ".span6" have width but user will insert them through backend so it will be dynamic and i have to calculate the widths of the inserted ".span3" and ".span6" of individual ".m-stage--container".